# How to change fragment programmatically on FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

I have created applicaiton by using Eclipse default ViewPager application parameters. Main activity contains 2 tabs(tabA and tabB). Each tab refers to its fragment(fragmentA and fragmentB).

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new Cars();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new News();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

On the second tab(tabB), there is a listview. I am trying to change fragment(without opening new activity) to new fragment(fragmentC) on second tab(tabB) when one list item is selected.

```
public class News extends ListFragment {
...
            ListAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), carsList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    TextView tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvId);


                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item was clicked. id:"+tvId.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?
                }
            });
```

How to change fragment inside FragmentPagerAdapter at the same time enabling "BACK" button(if back button will be pressed on fragmentC, it should return to fragmentB)?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?